# How to connect to oracle from a sharepoint solution?

Tags: 2013, 2010, development

I want to create a wsp which connects SharePoint to Oracle. On my research on this I came to know that I can use either Oracle.DataAccess dll or System.Data.OracleClient. But both of them are not sucessful.

Oracle.DataAccess dll can only be used with its dependencies. It throws error

> " Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format."

Also it cannot be added along with a wsp where as System.Data.OracleClient throws error

> "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw
>   BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64
>   bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."

Answer (score 1):

In order to work with Oracle, You need to make sure following things.

- Oracle Client Installed on all SharePoint Server
- **64 Bit** of [oracle client installed](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/132649/Attempt-to-load-Oracle-client-libraries-threw-BadI)
- make sure IIS also using the 64Bit. [check this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8cb5f3d-8e61-4e63-b325-d07b261f77ac/attempt-to-load-oracle-client-libraries-threw-badimageformatexception-this-problem-will-occur-when?forum=netfx64bit)

Comment: i had installed 32 bit client and compiled the project as 32 bit itself. But before going to sharepoint solution i created a c# webservice, hosted it in iis and set the enable 32 bit feature to true. Still it shows the same BadImageFormatException

Comment: i am not developer. in recent past, i had to install the Oracle Client 64bit, we tried 32 bit but did not work...reason Sharepoint is 64 bit, OS is 64 Bit